# How to make case classes "final" in some sense?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

So, Scala case classes are similar to ADTs but in case of ADTs the declaration has complete list of cases while with case classes it's not, so a function that takes an instance of this case class "family" could receive something unexpected and produce a run-time error. How to alleviate this problem? Let's say I have the following code

```
trait Animal

case class Cat extends Animal
case class Dog extends Animal

def say(a: Animal) = a match {
  case Cat => "meow"
  case Dog => "woof"
}
```

Then someone could extend the `Animal` trait and call `say` function. How to forbid any further extensions of the trait?

Comment: Actually case class is an Algebraic Data Type (also ADT).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you could make the animal trait `sealed`. Meaning: `sealed trait Animal`

`sealed` traits can only be extended by classes defined in the same source file.

In this way the compiler can also warn you if you considered all cases when you use pattern-matching on `Animal`.

Comment: @synapse one important note: if you have `sealed trait T` and `class/trait A` which extend T compiler indeed will force you to have them in the same file. BUT having a `class/trait B` in some **other file** which will extend A and thus original trait T is perfectly legal.

Comment: Also, the Java compiler is unaware of `sealed`, so Java classes can implement the sealed traits.